# Grouping js string array with counting

Tags: javascript

I have simple array in js

```
var fruit = [ 'apple' , 'apple' , 'orange' ]
```

I need this groped so that i can present data in format:

```
apple 2
orange 1
```

I have tried with creating two arrays but all got out off control .

Comment: Show us what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a way to do this:

```
var fruit = ['apple', 'apple', 'orange'];

var occurences = {};
for (var index = 0; index < fruit.length; index++) {
    var value = fruit[index];
    occurences[value] = occurences[value] ? occurences[value] + 1 : 1;
}

console.log(occurences);
```

The logged output is an object containing `apple: 2, orange: 1}` as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/zZ2hk/

Answer (score 3):

You can do this succinctly with with reduction:

```
function count(xs) {
  return xs.reduce(function(a,e) {
    return a[e] = ++a[e]||1, a;
  },{});
}

count(fruit); //=> {apple:2, orange:1}
```

Comment: I was just about to post a `reduce` of my own, but then I saw that short piece of beauty...

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate though `fruit` value and increment a counter:

```
var result = {};
for (var i = 0, n = fruit.length; i < n; i++) {
  if (typeof result[fruit[i]] === 'undefined') {
    result[fruit[i]] = 1;
  } else {
    result[fruit[i]]++;
  }
}

console.log(result); // Object {apple: 2, orange: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fruits = [ 'apple' , 'apple' , 'orange' ];
var result = {};

for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
    var item = fruits[i];
    result[item] = result[item] ? result[item] + 1 : 1;
}

console.log(result); // Object { apple=2,  orange=1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try underscore [countBy](http://underscorejs.org/#countBy) function:

```
var fruit = [ 'apple' , 'apple' , 'orange' ];
var count = _.countBy(fruit, function(el) {
    return el;
});
```

Also it has other very useful functions.

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com - The same counts for underscore. It's a nice library, yes, but maybe a bit too much for the requested functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fruit = [ 'apple' , 'apple' , 'orange' ];
var counts = {};

for(var i =0; i < fruit.length;i++){
    counts[fruit[i]] = (counts[fruit[i]]) ? counts[fruit[i]] + 1:1;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/FuXMu/2