# Count the occurences of the string in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Need to count the occurences of string in an array

```
userList=["abc@gmail.com","bca@gmail.com","abc@gmail.com"]
```

Need to get the count of each strings

`let userList=["abc@gmail.com","bca@gmail.com","abc@gmail.com"]`

Expected : `[{"abc@gmail.com":2},{"bca@gmail.com":1}]`

Comment: Oh nice yaar, please proceed

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Comment: Did you try searching before asking this question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouping js string array with counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549646) and [How to count the number of occurrences of each item in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649255)

Comment: Thanks @adiga, that's the one I was looking for

Comment: var userList = ["abc@gmail.com","bca@gmail.com","abc@gmail.com"];
    var tmpObj = {};
    
    for(var i = 0; i < userList.length; i++){
        if(tmpObj[userList[i]]){
            tmpObj[userList[i]]++;
        }
        else {
            tmpObj[userList[i]] = 1;
        }
    }
    
    var result = [];
    
    for(x in tmpObj){
        var obj = {};
        obj[x] = tmpObj[x];
        result.push(obj);
    }
    
    console.log(result);

Answer (score 1):

```
var userList=["abc@gmail.com","bca@gmail.com","abc@gmail.com"];

var result = Object.values(userList.reduce((acc, c)=>{
    if(!acc.hasOwnProperty(c)) { acc[c] = {[c]:0};}
    acc[c][c] += 1; 
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Hope this helps you !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method with a reference object which keeps the index of the element.

```js
let userList = ["abc@gmail.com", "bca@gmail.com", "abc@gmail.com"];

let ref = {};

let res = userList.reduce((arr, s) => (s in ref ? arr[ref[s]][s]++ : arr[ref[s] = arr.length] = { [s]: 1 }, arr), [])



console.log(res)



// or the same with if-else

// object for index referencing
let ref1 = {};

// iterate over the array
let res1 = userList.reduce((arr, s) => {
  // check if index already defined, then increment the value
  if (s in ref1)
    arr[ref1[s]][s]++;
  // else create new element and add index in reference array
  else
    arr[ref1[s] = arr.length] = { [s]: 1 };
  // return array reference
  return arr;
  // set initial value as empty array for result
}, []);

console.log(res1)
```